# Detect the traffic from a proxy or not

Tags: javascript, http, proxy, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I am trying to identify if the request which is generated from my app / client website is coming from a proxy or not. I have been trying to analyse the information of X-Forwarded-For, but it is not good enough as the proxy or a program could override the holding information of X-Forwarded-For.

I dont know if there is anything I could add to my app or my client website where originate the traffic / request. The only think I know is "pixel code" which could be a snippet of javascript code, but I not sure if there are any javascript function would be able to analyse the ip address.

Having say that, would it be possible to track the routing of the request from the origin (client side / app) to the destination (the server)? Or any other way that could help to identify the received request is bypass a proxy or a number of layers of proxy?

Is there anyway better than analysis the X-Forwarded-For?

Thanks you

Comment: performance.navigation might help, and you can use timing attacks to figure out the effective lag. you can also try reaching stuff that http proxies won't work with, and see if you get it back.

Comment: Hi, could you expand? what does performance navigation stand for? could u give me some examples about "reaching stuff that http proxies won't work with", I am still confuse about it